# Like Box "show more" button opens another Like Box in another tab

Tags: feed, facebook-likebox, browser-tab

In the like box, when i scroll down to the end of the news stream and click the show more button it opens the like box in a new tab. And doesn't show older news.

Please help.

Comment: Just noticed this myself; pretty sure it wasn't doing it a few days ago.  Googled and found this.

Comment: Equally mysteriously, seems to have started working as expected again.  How about for you ?